# How to get data between two date pickers for a virtual table (A place Holder)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So i have a sql statement in my C# Code to try and pull data between two date ranges. Only thing is, nothing shows up.

```
        OpenConnection(conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select CampaignName AS 'CAMPAIGN NAME', campaignDescription AS 'CAMPAIGN DESCRIPTION', CASE WHEN EndDate >= GETDATE() and StartDate <= GETDATE() THEN 'ACTIVE' WHEN StartDate >= GETDATE() THEN 'PENDING' ELSE 'CLOSED' END as 'CURRENT STATUS', CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), StartDate,106) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),EndDate,106) AS 'CAMPAIGN DATES', Discount AS 'DISCOUNT', [Target] AS 'TARGET', Uptake AS 'UPTAKE', AddedBy AS 'ADDED BY', DateAdded AS 'DATE ADDED' FROM Tbl_Campaign WHERE startDate BETWEEN @from AND @to", conn);

        try
        {

            SqlParameter param;
            param = new SqlParameter("@from", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            param.Value = txtStartDate.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            param = new SqlParameter("@to", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            param.Value = txtDateEnd.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
```

If you scroll to the end of my Sql Command, you will see two variables for my to and from date. I tried executing this piece of code in SQL, and it works if i manually parse the dates, with `''` quotation marks. I think thats what is why its not retrieving data. Could someone help me with this request?

Comment: Why do you add parameter values as a string since you defined their type as `SqlDbType.DateTime`? Have you ever try to parse your `txtStartDate` and `txtDateEnd` to `DateTime` first? And use `using` statement to dispose your connection, command and adapter automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

Comment: if that's the case.. try to replace `SqlDbType.DateTime` with `SqlDbType.String`

Comment: @SonerGönül Uhm im fairly new to programming, so its a little bit complicated for me. Im not too sure how to parse the txtStartDate and txtDateEnd to date time first. And thank you for the using statement, i will do that. Thought they both did the same thing.

Comment: And @LiranBo It doesnt give me the option to make it a SqlDbType.String. I Tried Varchar and its still not showing anything. Ive tried changing the format of my date, but then it wont fill the Data Adapter, it gives this message ------> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: @LiranBo [How to: Convert a String to a DateTime (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) or just search on Google https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=c%23+parse+string+to+datetime&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=QRs3VvKqBoGcaPuPhLAH

Comment: Cool thanks @LiranBo i will try follow those rules.

Answer (score 0):

I used a text box to get the date since your code includes "txtStartDate.Text". So, I tried your code with a simple query only to get the data in a date range. It works well. So, I think there's an issue in another place in your query. 
This is the code I tried:

```
        con = new SqlConnection();
        string _connectionString = GetConnectionString();
        con.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM FORDSUMD WHERE Dated BETWEEN @from AND @to",con);

        try
        {
            SqlParameter param;
            param = new SqlParameter("@from", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            param.Value = txtStartDate.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            param = new SqlParameter("@to", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            param.Value = txtDateEnd.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }   

    public string GetConnectionString(string databaseName = "", string serverName = "")
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder conString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverName))
            serverName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"];

        //Assing SQl server name
        conString.DataSource = serverName;
        conString.InitialCatalog = string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseName) ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBName"] : databaseName;
        conString.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        conString.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserId"];
        conString.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];

        return conString.ConnectionString;
    }
```

If you want to use DateTimePicker control instead of the textbox control, simply replace txtStartDate.Text by dtpStart.Value(DateTimePicker) and txtDateEnd.Text by dtpEnd.Value. It will work.